# Rails Path Helpers not selecting application host for requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got failing specs and when I go to inspect them, all requests are being made to `http://www.example.com`. So it seems pretty obvious to me that something is overriding the default host but when I grep the app for instances of `example.com` I cannot find anything causing it to direct requests there and to the contrary I have two places explicitly directing requests to localhost

`spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
  config.before(:each) do
    host! "https://localhost:3000"
  end
```

`config/environments/test.rb`

```
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

Any thoughts on what could be overriding this and how I could more aggressively force the route helpers to use localhost as the host?

Comment: There is a longstanding (ancient) issue (e.g., https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/546) with setting `default_url_options` on integration tests, because `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` ignores all the sensible ways you'd expect to set the default options. Most of the suggested solutions suggest monkey patching `ActionDispatch` in one way or another depending on the version of Rails you are using.

Comment: @rmlockerd wow good find! If you'd like to basically write that as an answer I'd accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmlockerd mentioned above, this seems to go back to an old issue with action dispatch that may have somehow resurfaced with Rails 6

It's caused by this code in `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` which hard codes `example.com` as the `DEFAULT_HOST`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d45baa34445379319f5c46f6d13f52e6dd79bc9a/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L84

There is some further info in this rails issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/546

Given that, you can monkey patch that class to set your default host and protocol to whatever you want. Probably terrible and I'm sure there's a better way but I don't know what it is.

So in the main scope in my `rails_helper.rb` I added

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Integration #:nodoc:
    class Session
      DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost"

      def https?
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```